Numerical analysis of simultaneous differential equations using NDSolve
Nowadays I tried to solve a simultaneous differential equations using NDSolve.
The problem that what I want to solve is,

There are two field configurations are exist: phi[t] and h[t,f].
h[t,f] is dependent on the phi[t], so h [t, f] is composite phi [t] and other constants.
phi[t] and h[t,f] has their own equation of motion

My full code is,
(* Initial Parameters *)
α0 = 1.4;
ε0 = 0.95;
r0 = 1.1;

λ = 0.1289;
Λ = 130; (* GeV *)
Λc = 983.75; (* GeV *)

v0 = 246; (* GeV *)
μ = 60; (* GeV - arbitrary *)
M = 95.039; (* GeV *)

θ0 = ArcSin[(-Sin[α0])/(Sqrt[1 + 2 r0 ε0 Cos[α0] + r0^2 ε0^2])];
yt = 0.95;
Tn = 85.5359; (* GeV *)
ch = 0.3467;

f1 = 10^5; (* GeV *)
f2 = 10^6; (* GeV *)
f3 = 10^6.5; (* GeV *)
f4 = 10^7; (* GeV *)

(* T-t Relation: Defines the temperature as a function of time *)
T[t_] := 1.12*10^(-3) t^(-1/2); (* GeV *)

(* Oscillation Start Point: Determines when oscillations begin based on f *)
tosc[f_] := (1.12*10^(-3))^2/(25*10^3 ((Λ^2/f)/(10^(-2)))^(3/17) (Λc/10^3)^(11/17))^2;

(* Mass of the ALP: Calculates the mass of axion-like particles as a function of time and f *)
mΦ[t_, f_] := Min[((Λ^2/f) (Λc/(1.12*10^(-3) t^(-1/2)))^(11/3))^(6/17), Λ^2/f];

(* Higgs Field Calculations *)
μHT2[t_, f_] := μ^2 - M^2 Cos[Φ[t]/f + α0] + (ch*(1.12*10^(-3))^2)/t;
h[t_, f_] := If[μHT2[t, f] >= 0, 0, Sqrt[-μHT2[t, f]/λ]];

(* Derivative Potentials for φ and h *)
VdΦ[t_, f_] := (1/f)*((Λ^4)*Sin[Φ[t]/f] + (M^2)*(h[t, f]^2)*Sin[(Φ[t]/f) + α0])
Vdh[t_, f_] := -(λ/4) (h[t, f]^3);

(* Thermal Dissipation Rate *)
Γth[t_, f_] := 1.12*10^(-4) (mΦ[t, f])^(1/2) t^(-1/2);

Γh[t_, f_] := Max[yt^4 (h[t, f])^2/Γth[t, f], Γth[t, f]*(yt)^2];
Γhinit[t_, f_] := Γth[t, f]*(yt)^2;
Γhfin[t_, f_] := yt^4 (h[t, f])^2/Γth[t, f];

(* Equations of Motion for φ and h *)
EOMΦ[t_, f_] := D[Φ[t], {t, 2}] + VdΦ[t, f]/(mΦ[t, f])^2 == 0;
EOMh[t_, f_] := D[h[t, f], {t, 2}] + Γh[t, f]*D[h[t, f], t]/mΦ[t, f] + Vdh[t, f]/(mΦ[t, f])^2 == 0;

(* Initial Conditions for Differential Equations *)
tinit[f_] := tosc[f]*mΦ[tosc[f], f];
initialConditions[f_] := {
    Φ[tinit[f]] == 0, 
    Derivative[1][Φ][tinit[f]] == 0.1, 
    h[tinit[f], f] == 0, 
    Derivative[1][h][tinit[f], f] == 0.1
};

(* Numerical Solution of the Equations of Motion *)
solf1 = NDSolve[
    {EOMΦ[t, f1], EOMh[t, f1], initialConditions[f1]},
    {Φ[t], h[t, f1]},
    {t, tinit[f1], 500},
    DependentVariables -> {Φ[t], h[t, f1]}
];

(* Plotting the results *)
plotf1 = Plot[Evaluate[h[t, f1] /. solf1], {t, tinit[f1], 500},
    PlotLabel -> Style["h(t, f1) vs Time", 28],
    PlotStyle -> RGBColor[1, 0, 0],
    GridLines -> Automatic,
    PlotRange -> All,
    ImageSize -> 360
];

And it returns error messages below
NDSolve::litarg: To avoid possible ambiguity, the arguments of the dependent variable in If[3600+4.349*10^-7/t-9032.41 Cos[1.4 +\[Phi][<<1>>]/100000]>=0,0,Sqrt[-(\[Mu]HT2[t,100000]/\[Lambda])]] should literally match the independent variables.

ReplaceAll::reps: {NDSolve[{(Times[<<3>>]+Times[<<2>>])/(100000 Min[<<2>>]^2)+(\[Phi]^\[Prime]\[Prime])[t]==0,If[Plus[<<3>>]>=0,0,Times[<<2>>]+Times[<<2>>]]-(0.032225 If[<<3>>]^3)/Min[<<2>>]^2+(If[GreaterEqual[<<2>>],0,Times[<<4>>]] Max[Times[<<4>>],Times[<<3>>]])/Min[<<2>>]==0,{\[Phi][3.25924*10^-18]==0,(\[Phi]^\[Prime])[3.25924*10^-18]==0.1,If[Plus[<<2>>]>=0,0,Sqrt[Times[<<2>>]]]==0,(h^\[Prime])[3.25924*10^-18,100000]==0.1}},{\[Phi][t],If[3600+4.349*10^-7 Power[<<2>>]-9032.41 Cos[<<1>>]>=0,0,Sqrt[-(\[Mu]HT2[<<2>>]/\[Lambda])]]},{t,3.25924*10^-18,500},DependentVariables->{\[Phi][t],If[3600+Times[<<2>>]+Times[<<2>>]>=0,0,Sqrt[<<2>> Power[<<2>>]]]}]} is neither a list of replacement rules nor a valid dispatch table, and so cannot be used for replacing.

NDSolve::dsvar: 0.010214285714285717` cannot be used as a variable.

I spend almost a week to fix this code, but there are no other person here to help my work.
Now I still stucked in this problem.
I think this problem caused in this line. (but I'm not sure about it)
(* Initial Conditions for Differential Equations *)
tinit[f_] := tosc[f]*mΦ[tosc[f], f];
initialConditions[f_] := {
    Φ[tinit[f]] == 0, 
    Derivative[1][Φ][tinit[f]] == 0.1, 
    h[tinit[f], f] == 0, 
    Derivative[1][h][tinit[f], f] == 0.1
};

My intention is h[tinit[f],f]==0 with phi[tinit[f]]==0
But program understand it h[init[f],f]==0 with phi[t], so it returns NDSolve::litarg: error.
However. I'm NOT sure it my idea is right, and I can't think any solution for fix it.
I need to help for problem recognization and how can I make corrections.
Any advice to solve my problem or improve my code is welcome.
Please help me.

It could be nice to add some explanation of your model in Latex form.
